# Закрывается форма если не отгадываю число на c#

Tags: c#

Задача заключается в том, что я пишу число в textBox и если не отгадываю, то форма закрывается, а должно быть так, если я не отгадываю число, то  я нажимаю на Button, очищается textBox и заново угадывать до тех пор, пока не угадаю. В чем ошибка?

```
namespace pzacy_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        const int del = 10; // максимальное число, которое угадывается 
        Random rnd;
        int x, y, prize = 100; //i=x , k=y

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            x = rnd.Next(del);
            y = 0;
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox1.Focus();
            label3.Text = "";

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rnd = new Random();
            x = rnd.Next(del);
            textBox1.Clear();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n;
            //if (e.KeyChar != (char)13) return;
            n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            if (n>x)
            {
                label3.Text = "Не угадали! Введите число меньше";
                prize = -10;
            }
            if (n < x)
            {
                label3.Text = "Не угадали! Введите число больше";
                prize = -10;
            }
            if (n == x)
            {
                label3.Text = "Правильно!" + prize;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Форма закрывается потому что вызывается исключение FormatException. А приложение его не отлавливает.

Добавьте try catch в Text changed. Либо конвертируйте чтоб не выбрасывало исключение. Подробнее можно посмотреть [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/20.4.php)

Как то так

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try {
        int n;
        //if (e.KeyChar != (char)13) return;
        n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        if (n>x)
        {
            label3.Text = "Не угадали! Введите число меньше";
            prize = -10;
        }
        if (n < x)
        {
            label3.Text = "Не угадали! Введите число больше";
            prize = -10;
        }
        if (n == x)
        {
            label3.Text = "Правильно!" + prize;
        }
      } catch {
      }
    }
```

Comment: Aziz Umarov             int n;
            string name = textBox1.Text;
            try
            {
                n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Некорретно заданы числовые данные";
            }

Comment: Aziz Umarov все равно закрывается

Comment: Оберните весь метод. У вас ещё что то там есть. И на catch по сути ничего не надо. Вы запускаете цикл изменений

Comment: Aziz Umarov в смысле обернуть весь метод?

Comment: Уберите textBox.Text = вы этим зацикливание исключения

Comment: Нужно правильно обрабатывать исключения. В вашем случае добавьте try catch на все операции в методе text changed и ничего не делайте на catch c textbox.

Comment: Text changed сработает на все изменения и на программные тоже. Аккуратнее с ним

Comment: Aziz Umarov Спасибо, все работает! Все события, которые были в textBox1_TextChanged я написал в try {(события)} и после него catch(). Верно?

Comment: Да я ответ уже поменял добавил примерное поведение. Это для учебы. В реальности нужно аккуратнее быть и обрабатывать верно события и исключения